# checkbox inputs are checked by default?

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I have some checkbox inputs in my vue app that I am trying to render as unchecked but for some reason they stay checked

my data looks like so:

```
 data: {
                students: [
                    {
                        "id": 189,
                        "first_name": "el Mahdi",
                        "avatar": null,
                        "group_id": 24,
                        "full_name": ", el Mahdi",
                        "exclude": false,
                        "isGrouped": false, 
                        "include": false,
                    }, {
                        "id": 190,
                        "first_name": "Walid",
                        "avatar": null,
                        "group_id": 24,
                        "full_name": ", Walid",
                        "exclude": false,
                        "isGrouped": false, 
                        "include": false, 
                    }]
}
```

and my html looks like the following

```
   <li v-for="absentStudent in absentStudents" class="list-unstyled">
                        <input type="checkbox" @change="check($event)" v-model="absentStudentsSelected" :value="absentStudent.id">
                        {{ absentStudent.first_name }}
                    </li>
```

I don't know where the checked="true" attribute is being set from at all but when I check my elements in the console, the value is set to checked and that's how it renders in the DOM

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Please include the codes related to the check boxes like `absentStudents` (if it is computed value of `students`), `check()` and `absentStudentsSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

```
checked="false"
```

This right there is your problem.  will only take "checked" as a positive attribute for when you checked a checkbox, but "checked" takes no further arguments. Writing it the way you did will make the browser read the "checked" part and ignore the rest, therefore rendering the box checked.

Check out the MDN page on that specific input type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Remove `checked="false"` from your input, Vue will add this attribute when user check it.

```
<li v-for="absentStudent in absentStudents" class="list-unstyled">
    <input type="checkbox" @change="check($event)" v-model="absentStudentsSelected" :value="absentStudent.id" >
    {{ absentStudent.first_name }}
</li>
```

**UPDATE**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    absentStudentsSelected: [],
    students: [{
      "id": 189,
      "first_name": "el Mahdi",
      "avatar": null,
      "group_id": 24,
      "full_name": ", el Mahdi",
      "exclude": false,
      "isGrouped": false,
      "include": false,
    }, {
      "id": 190,
      "first_name": "Walid",
      "avatar": null,
      "group_id": 24,
      "full_name": ", Walid",
      "exclude": false,
      "isGrouped": false,
      "include": false,
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <li v-for="absentStudent in students" class="list-unstyled">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="absentStudentsSelected" :value="absentStudent.id"> {{ absentStudent.first_name }}
  </li>
  
  {{absentStudentsSelected}}
</div>
```

Comment: I have removed the attribute and opened another instance of the app but unfortunately the issue persists. I will edit my code here to reflect the changes.

Comment: It looks ok, maybe `@change` fires, I update my answer to check a simple implementation

Comment: I've tried using '@click ' instead of @change but that still doesn't seem to effect the default